# Why can't I create groovy/Grails project in Eclipse and Netbeans?

Tags: eclipse, grails, netbeans

**System**: Ubuntu 16.04
**Eclipse**: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)
**Netbeans**: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)

```
$ java -version  
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"  
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-2ubuntu0.16.04.2-b14)  
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_80

$ grails -version
Grails version: 2.3.11
```

1. Netbeans issue -

Trying to create a Grails project from Netbeans leads to the following error in **New project wizard**

```
 Not all requested modules can be enabled: [Standard module
 org.netbeans.modules.groovy.kit jarFile: home/user_Me/software/netbeans-8.2/groovy/modules/org-netbeans-modules-groovy-kit.jar]
```

My `netbeans.conf` file has the following set as JAVA_Home

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"
```

---

2. Eclipse issue -

Using the route, **new project > create new project > grails > grails project**

leads to this error:

```
No Grails installation configured
```

So I tried configuring grails installation, and added grails home with following path:

```
/home/user_Me/.sdkman/candidates/grails/2.3.11/bin/
```

which still gives error:

```
Specified directory does not appear to be a Grails installation
```

Netbeans gives the same error for creation of other projects like JAVA, Maven, PHP, html and so on!

I thought maybe the conflicting java and javac versions might be creating some problems and went through following solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/300564/netbeans-install-error-the-specified-jdk-folder-does-not-contain-jdk]

however I was not able to solve the issue.

Why cant I create an empty Grails project even though I can run Grails commands through terminal?

Answer (score 1):

A work arround is to create the project in terminal

```
grails create-app testApp
```

and then import it into either intelliJ or eclipse